# Notation for Surface Integral in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: integration, notation, surfaces

Recently, a paper of mine got accepted, but the reviewers are struggling with the (in my view) standard notation for surface integrals in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

Let $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a 2-dimensional surface, parametrized by $\varphi:\Omega \rightarrow \Gamma$ (where $\Omega$ is a domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$). Having a scalar function $f:\Gamma\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, I would write

$$\int_{\Gamma} f(\gamma)dS(\gamma) = \int_{\Omega}f(\varphi(x))\left|\varphi_{x_1}(x)\times\varphi_{x_2}(x)\right|dx.$$

The LHS is what I wrote and the reviewers did not understand it... they "expect[ed] $dS(\gamma)$ to be $\gamma$" and other strange stuff. I have to mention, it is a paper at a *computer vision conference*.

What do you think? Which notation is in your view the most "standard" one? Do you think I can expect from the reader to understand a notation like $\int_{\Gamma} f(\gamma)dS(\gamma)$?

Comment: Using $\Gamma$ to denote a 2-dimensional surface may be part of what's throwing them off (I did a double take myself), because it's usually used to denote 1-dimensional curves.

Comment: The $f(\gamma) dS(\gamma)$ confuses me as well. Rewriting it as $$\int\limits_{\Gamma} f \, dS = \int\limits_{\Omega} f(\varphi(x)) | \varphi_{x_1}(x) \times \varphi_{x_2} (x) | \,dx$$ may clear it up.

Comment: I understand $dS(\gamma)$ as surface element at $\gamma \in \Gamma$. In my view this is the most exact formulation.

Comment: The problem is I really need the $\gamma$ to appear in the surface element, since my original integral is looking like $$x\mapsto \int_\Gamma f(x,\gamma)dS(\gamma).$$

Comment: I'm confused, haha. I got $\gamma \in \Gamma$ but what does that mapping do?

Comment: @DavidH: I did not use $\Gamma$ in my paper, but $\mathbb{S}^3$. But I really hope this should never confuse anybody, as long as I make clear that $\Gamma$ (or whatever letter/sign I use) is a 2-dim surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Fantini: In difference to the plane world the area element depends on the position at which I am on my surface, that is where the cross product on the RHS is coming from... if you need a deeper explanation you may find more details at e.g. wikipedia.

Comment: @Fantini: In my view $\int_\Gamma fdS$ is just an abbreviatory notation of $\int_\Gamma f(x)dS(x)$. It is used often with good reason, since often no confusion arises from this...

Comment: The area element yes, but why $f(x,\gamma)?$ And I agree, the usual abbreviatory notation does not lead to confusion. Even though your area element depends on the point considered, since you are integrating it should not matter, because regardless you are summing over the entire domain.

Comment: Your mapping takes a point in the domain to the integral of the function $f: \Gamma \to \Bbb R$ (which does not depend on the domain, so far) over the surface. What does it mean?

Comment: @Fantini: I am not exactly sure what you are asking for. Shall I explain the meaning of a surface integral? Should I add an example for a surface integral to my question, where $f$ and $\Gamma$ "get a face", maybe? On the otherhand, I expect this to go beyond the scope of this question...

Comment: I understand it fine, but if the reviewers are having trouble, why not just remove explicit reference to $\gamma$?  It's implied by $\int_\Gamma fdS$, anyway.  Edit: I guess that won't work if your actual integral is $x\mapsto \int_\Gamma f(x,\gamma)dS(\gamma)$.  I don't know what to tell you.  It makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

A differential form is sometimes written with the point as subscript, so, for example, if we denote $dS$ the 2-form of the area element at a point $\gamma$ we can write it also as $dS_\gamma$. Remember that a 2-form takes a couple of tangent vectors (whose area it computes) as arguments written in the brackets: $dS_\gamma(u,v)$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe define $f_x(\gamma)$ instead of $f(x, \gamma)$ and go with $x\mapsto \int_\Gamma f_xdS$, unless the $dS$ part itself causes confusion.

Comment: Hi Tom. Thank you for your suggestion. However, this is too much overhead and highly complicates my notation (for nothing). So: Thank you to all for this discussion! For me it seems to be the best way to ignore the reviewers' headaches at this point. But still: If anybody has any new suggestion, I will gratefully read it :-)